# How to print function output in ScrolledText tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have trouble entering the output of a function in another `scrolledtext` class, which I have simplified so that I can better explain.
I have a function in a class (named `A`) and I want to write it's print content in `ScrolledText` in another class (`B`) like below:

```
import time
class A:
    def func(self):
        for i in range(0, 4):
            print(i)
            time.sleep(0.5)
        pass
```

I use this method but I do not get an answer:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
In[1]:class B:
          root = Tk()
          def finish():
              text.insert(INSERT, A().func()) # Here I have tried to write in the ScrolledText
                                              # But it does not work
          text = ScrolledText(root)
          text.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

          button_openfile = Button(root, text = 'Start', command = finish)
          button_openfile.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

          root.mainloop()

In[2]:if __name__ == "__main__": 
          B()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting the text in the `ScrolledText` widget because:

```
text.insert(INSERT, A().func())
```

In this line, the second parameter(`A().func()`) is supposed to be a `String`.

```
print(i)
```

When the function is called, Instead of returning the `String` or text, you just printed it in the terminal. Instead you should return a text.